# BST Only Keeps Last Inserted Value and Makes it Root

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to populate a binary search tree using an insert(), however when every I 'print' the contents of my BST, I only get the last item that was inserted into the BST. What do I need to fix to make sure all of my value are retaining in the BST?

From debuggin, I think that my problem is that my public void insert() is setting the new value to root evertime it is called. I don't know how to fix it?

Here is my BST CLass:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {

private class BinarySearchTreeNode<E>{
    public BinarySearchTreeNode<E> left, right;
    private E data;

    private BinarySearchTreeNode (E data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

private BinarySearchTreeNode<T> root;

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return root == null;
} 
private BinarySearchTreeNode<T> insert(T value, BinarySearchTreeNode<T> ptr) {
            if (ptr == null){ 
        ptr = new BinarySearchTreeNode<>(value); 
        return ptr; 
    }
    int compare = value.compareTo(ptr.data); //when ptr != null, this line and below should execute for each bstStrings.inster(x)
    /* pass the value (s1...sN) when compared to (ptr.data) to compare
     * when value and ptr.data == 0 re
     */
    if (compare == 0) {
        return ptr;
    }
    if (compare < 0) {
        while (ptr.left != null){
            ptr = ptr.left;
            if (ptr.left == null) {//found insertion point
                BinarySearchTreeNode<T> node = new BinarySearchTreeNode<>(value);
                ptr = ptr.left;
                ptr = node;
                return ptr;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return insert(value, ptr.left);
    }
    if (compare > 0) {              
        if (ptr.right == null) {
            BinarySearchTreeNode<T> node = new BinarySearchTreeNode<>(value);
            ptr = ptr.right;
            ptr = node;
            return ptr;
        } 
    }
    else {
        return insert(value, ptr.right);                    
    }
    return ptr;
}
public void insert(T value) {
    root = insert(value, root);  //****Where I believe the problem is******
} 
private void printTree(BinarySearchTreeNode<T>node){
    if(node != null){
        printTree(node.left);
        System.out.println(" " + node.data);
        printTree(node.right);
    }
}
public void printTree(){
    printTree(root);
    System.out.println();
}    
}
```

For added context here is my Main() where I am calling the insert() and trying to insert strings into the BST:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BinarySearchTree<String> bstStrings = new BinarySearchTree<String>();

    String s = "Hello";
    String s1 = "World";
    String s2 = "This Morning";
    String s3 = "It's";

    bstStrings.insert(s);
    bstStrings.insert(s1);
    bstStrings.insert(s2);
    bstStrings.insert(s3);   //the only inserted value that is printed below

    bstStrings.printTree();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You should have values above this line!");
}
}
```

Lastly my console output:

```
It's


You should have values above this line!
```

Comment: I don't see any recursive calls inside `insert`. I think that's one part of the problem. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some hints:

- I don't see any recursive calls inside `insert`. How would you traverse the BST without appropriate recursive calls (into the left or right subtree of the current node based on the value)? I do see some commented out code that looks like it would perform those calls. Why are they commented out?
- You're returning the newly inserted node, which you're then setting as `root`. This will set the `root` to point to the new node *every time*. I don't think that's what you want.
- If you're trying to handle the special case where the tree is empty, all you need to do is check to see if `root` is `null`, then set the new node to that.
- There really is no need to return `ptr`. Since your BST maintains a reference to `root`, you always have a reference to the root of the tree. Every time you insert, you start with the `root` and then recursively traverse the tree until you find a suitable place to insert the new node. If you really must return the reference, then you most certainly should not be setting `root` to that new node!

Here is some pseudocode to help you out:

```
// Recursive function that inserts a value into a BST
function insert(node, value):

    //Handles the case where you have no nodes in the tree, so root is null
    if node is null:
        node = new Node(value)

    // If the value is lesser than the current node's value, we need to insert it
    // somewhere in the right subtree
    else if value < node.value:
        if node.right is null:
           // This node doesn't have a right child, so let's insert the new node here
           node.right = new Node(value)
        else:
           // This node has a right child, so let's go further into this subtree to
           // find the right place to insert the new node
           insert(node.right, value)

    // If the value is greater than the current node's value, we need to insert it
    // somewhere in the left subtree
    else if value > node.value:
        if node.left is null:
           // This node doesn't have a left child, so let's insert the new node here
           node.left = new Node(value)
        else:
           // This node has a left child, so let's go further into this subtree to 
           // find the right place to insert the new node
           insert(node.left, value)
    else:
        // A node with this value already exists so let's print out an erro
        error("Node with that value already exists")

end function
```

Comment: It's not really homework, in that I don't have an assignment to turn in; it is however something I'm trying become more familar with incase one of our next projects requires it...I had those commented out because it was skipping from 'ptr = ptr.left' or 'ptr.right' in the compare >< 0 tests, directly to the recursive tests without created the new nodes

Comment: @ChristopherDay ah, ok. I will post some pseudocode to help you out and point you in the right direction! I don't want to deprive you of the enjoyment of figuring it out yourself :)

Comment: I appreciate any help you're willing to provide! I'm going to update my OP because uncommenting is cause a 'unreachable code' error. I'm going to revert back to some older code that had the same result though.

Comment: VICTORY IS MINE!!! Took a few tries but I'm getting increasing proficient at using the debugger and understaning how things look inside of it -Cheers.